# Javascript multi-DOM or multi-threading or alternative to isolate execution of upload

Tags: javascript, multithreading, dom

After starting down the path of using web workers I have realized that the library I require uses hidden iframe's and other DOM manipulation, even with the user interface disabled. Web workers seem to be the only multi-threading solution for JavaScript, but they understandably can't access the DOM directly.

**I haven't found any reference to creating a separate DOM object which acts like a separate tab that can potentially get it's own thread. Are hidden iframes treated this way typically in browsers? If not, are there any other methods to isolate or prioritize my UI from other execution besides Workers?**

My issue could potentially be solved or at least minimized by using a separate thread, though it is avoiding the underlying issue which could be performance or exist in third party libraries.

**Symptom:**
UI responsiveness goes down to zero and the thread pegs to 100% CPU on that core. This can last 0 to 30 seconds, sometimes even prompting the browser to ask about stopping the script. If uploads are disabled, this issue does not occur. It does not occur every time, but seems to happen more than 50% of the time if the UI or background-uploads are executing concurrently.

I need a solution so that the user has full responsiveness and can continue to navigate the site (single page application) after initiating an upload.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what your question is, but any CPU spiking that you're noticing is a product of the machine, browser, browser plugins, configuration options, etc. you haven't provided any information needed to start troubleshooting that issue, if that is what you are looking to address. The iframes are used solely to support IE9 and older, since this is literally the only way to allow multiple files to be uploaded concurrently in those browsers.

Comment: If you are not utilizing any of the UI modules as you say, and are on a modern browser, then the only DOM element is a file input. It's not clear why you think web workers will provide any sort of performance gains on a machine that is already utilizing 100% cpu, or how this benefit uploading files in general since these are not limited by the ui thread anyway. Again, you'll need to specify the exact question you have and provide specific information needed to address that issue.

Comment: Thanks Ray, excellent product (FU). It is single-core 90-100% CPU spike eg the browser tab process and could well be the SPA library or a combination causing the trouble. My thought is isolating it in a web-worker would allow the browser to delegate it to a separate thread and improve the UI responsiveness. I expect browsers vary in terms of how they delegate a new thread when using Web-workers. I am going to try modifying your library to remove references to the DOM if I can successfully pass a FileList into a Web Worker. Thanks for letting me know, I don't care about IE9.

Comment: I can assure you that sending http requests is not a cpu drain and delegating this to a web worker will not result in any perf gains. In fact, passing around blobs from the ui thread to a web worker will likely slow down your app further.

Comment: If you are seeing unusual cpu usage, I would suggest profiling your app in, for example, chrome dev tools first to figure out exactly where the problem lies.